# How can I set an Image's effect via trigger on its parent's IsChecked property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my view, I have several ToggleButtons. Each of them has an Image with a different source as its content, and its IsChecked property is bound to a property in my view model. I want to add/remove a DropShadowEffect to each button's Image, depending on whether its button IsChecked or not. I could give each Image its own style, with a DataTrigger on MyProperty1, MyProperty2, etc, but can I also do this with a single style for all images?

```
<ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding MyProperty1}" >
    <Image Source="{Binding MyIcon1}">
        <Image.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Direction="-45" ShadowDepth="3" />
        </Image.Effect>
    </Image>
</ToggleButton>

<ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding MyProperty2}" >
    <Image Source="{Binding MyIcon2}">
        <Image.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Direction="-45" ShadowDepth="3" />
        </Image.Effect>
    </Image>
</ToggleButton>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create common style for `Image` and use `DataTrigger` on `ToggleButton.IsChecked` property

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}" x:Key="imageButtonStyle">
        <Setter Property="Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect Direction="-45" ShadowDepth="3" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ToggleButton}}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding MyProperty2}" >
    <Image Source="{Binding MyIcon2}" Style="{StaticResource imageButtonStyle}"/>
</ToggleButton>
```